# Struct com vetor de char

Tags: c++, fila

Então pessoal, criei essa struct

```
typedef struct{
    int inicio;
    int tamanho;
    int fim;
    char *elementos[50];
}Fila;
```

E tenho por intenção criar um vetor de char, assim como eu criei várias vezes um vetor de inteiros. Só que não está dando certo na hora de implementação da função de criar a fila.

```
Fila* criarFila(int tamanho){
    Fila* novaFila = new Fila;
    novaFila->tamanho = tamanho;
    novaFila->inicio = -1;
    novaFila->fim = -1;
    novaFila->elementos = new char[tamanho];

    return novaFila;
}
```

Na hora de compilar, me gera o erro:

```
listar.cpp:66:22: error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘char*’ to   ‘char* [50]’
  novaFila->elementos = new char[tamanho];
                      ^
```

Alguém entende por que está gerando esse erro?

Comment: Tenta trocar `char *elementos[50];` por `char elementos[50];`

Answer (score 0):

```
char *elementos[50];
```

Assim você está criando um array de 50 ponteiros do tipo char.
Provávelmente o que você quer é só um ponteiro (aí o new char[tamanho] vai funcionar):

```
char *elementos;
```

Ou, se quiser um array de tamanho fixo:

```
char elementos[50];
```

Neste caso, ele será alocado junto com a struct (não precisa usar new).